# Gender-independent replacement for “fiancée” and “fiancé”

Tags: synonyms, kinship-terms, hypernyms, gender-neutral

I can use *child* to replace *son* or *daughter*, *sibling* for *sister* or *brother*, and *parent* for *mother* or *father*.

What is the unisex replacement for *fiancée* and *fiancé*?

I don’t need it for speech, but for formal or semi-formal writing.

Comment: He/She is 'spoken for'

Comment: Is there one for aunt/uncle? Do gender neutral terms necessarily exist in all cases?

Comment: @barrycarter: A sibling of my parent's? :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut How about bride/groom? (not "spouse", since that's after they're married).

Comment: @barrycarter: Person getting married?  (I'm being somewhat facetious — these names aren't very good!)

Comment: The English word _fiance_ /fian'se/ needs no accent (English orthography has no accents), and refers to intendeds of any gender. It's only in written French that gender appears. So as long as you're not writing in French, just drop the extra E and the accent. If you are writing in French, English advice won't help you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For formal writing, ***betrothed*** would be my number one choice. But, as Lunatik already gave that answer, I'll provide some more: ***spouse-to-be*** (instead of the gender-specific *wife-to-be* and *husband-to-be*), ***future spouse***, ***prospective spouse***, ***intended*** (date and informal).

Of course, it's much easier to refer to use adjectives and refer to the couple as a whole, if you can rewrite it in this way. This opens the door to: *engaged*, *affianced*, *pledged in marriage*, etc.

Answer (score 6):

"Betrothed" can be used as a noun, but I admit it does sound a bit stuffy.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to use *fiance* (no accent). In my experience most people aren't aware of the distinction between *fiancée* and *fiancé*, since it isn't reflected in speech, and simply reverting to the shorter form and leaving off the accent (to confound francophones) may be sufficient.

Comment: Though purposefully making mistakes doesn't sound fit for “formal or semi-formal writing”, does it?

Comment: @F'x: Writing *fiance* is not a mistake, as the accent-less version is endorsed as an alternate spelling by every dictionary I checked.

Comment: If your going to drop the accent, I'd suggest using fiancee. It retains the apparent last syllable, and follows nicely with "employee" and other "actee" words.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, "fiancé" was used male and "fiancée" for female; however, this is not reliably followed today, and "fiancé" is often used as a gender-neutral term.

> Matt called his fiancé and told her to come to the office.

-- 2018, T. K. Kohl, Quest of the Staff and the Sword, page 153.

Use "fiancé".

Comment: The comment made earlier by F'x, to a similar answer, applies to this one as well: 'purposefully making mistakes doesn't sound fit for “formal or semi-formal writing”'.